# How to use two concatMap?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following code:

```
event.afterClosed()
  .pipe((filter(Boolean), 
         concatMap(() => this.applicationSubjectsService.get(this.id),
         concatMap(() => this.applicationThemesService.get(this.id)
    )))
```

I would execute two sequence requests. How to get result from each and add to local variable?

I have tried this:

```
event.afterClosed()
  .pipe((filter(Boolean), 
         concatMap(() => this.applicationSubjectsService.get(this.id), finilize((response) =>  this.localSubjects = response),
         concatMap(() => this.applicationThemesService.get(this.id),
         finilize((response) =>  this.localThemes = response),
    )))
```

How to do that correctly and what should I change if I need execute at least one request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the tap operator to hook into the result from the switchMap. You can read about the tap operator here: [tap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap)

```
event.afterClosed()
   .pipe((filter(Boolean), 
       concatMap(() => this.applicationSubjectsService.get(this.id)),
       tap((result) => this.localSubjects = result),
       concatMap(() => this.applicationThemesService.get(this.id)),
       tap((result) => this.localThemes = result))
)
```

Comment: Yes, but problems is that if `concatMap`has error it calls `tap()` anyway?

Comment: If the first request fails the chain will be disposed and no `tap()` will be triggered.

Comment: using tap operator on the concatMap is a better approach in my opinion ( inner pipe)

Comment: Could I use a new pipe for each `concatMap`?

Comment: @MeganClerk yes

Comment: And inside pipe to use tap? What is difference if toy use tap outside after each concatpMap? What if error occurs?

Comment: You should have an catchError operator regardless to handle errors. You can choose whether you would pipe the concatMap with a tap and catchError OR to keep it as my answer and catchError on the main stream.